# Is there any difference between the elements in $\mathbb{C}[x]$ and $C^{\omega}$?

Tags: polynomials, hilbert-spaces, analytic-functions

Studying Hilbert spaces, I've been told that $\{1, x, x^2,\dots, x^k,\dots\}$ form a basis (**EDIT**: when orthonormalised) in $\mathcal{L}^2([a,b])$ because the set of all polynomial functions is dense in $C^0([a,b])$, which is dense in $\mathcal{L}^2([a,b])$. I'm going to assume all functions here are complex functions of real variable, so $[a,b]\subseteq\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$.

That got me thinking... if $C^{\omega}([a,b])$ is the set of all analytic functions defined in $[a,b]$, which by definition of analytic can be expressed as a Taylor series (which is basically a finite or infinite polynomial), is there a natural identification between analytic functions and polynomials?, or do the elements in $\mathbb{C}[x]$ have to be polynomials of finite degree (ignoring 0)? If so, what would be the difference between a basis in $C^{\omega}([a,b])$ and a basis in $\mathbb{C}[x]$ made of all finite-degree monomials?

Comment: $C^{\omega}([a,b])$ should denote the set of real analytic functions. If you want to deal with complex functions, you should replace it by $C^{\omega}(B_r(z_0))$ , $B_r(z_0)$ = open disk around $z_0$ wit radius $r$. In the first interpretation it doesn't make sense to compare it with $\mathbb{C}[x]$. Or you have to replace $\mathbb{C}[x]$ by $\mathbb{R}[x]$.

Comment: @PaulFrost in class, we deal with complex functions of real variable, so the coefficients are complex but the possible values of $x$ are real. I edited the question to make that clearer.

Comment: The difference: the monomials truly do generate all of $\mathbb C[x]$ as a vector space, but they are only a $topological$ basis for $\mathcal L^2([a,b])$ (which is to say the vector space they generate in $\mathcal L^2([a,b])$ is dense in the space). You can see there is no natural identification because $\mathbb C[x]$ has countable dimension, and $\mathcal L^2([a,b])$ has uncountable dimension (both  as $\mathbb C$-vector spaces).

Comment: @TokenToucan is there any sort of equivalence relation between the elements of $\mathcal{L}^2([a,b])$ that allows it (well, its quotient set) to be naturally identifiable with $\mathbb{C}[x]$? (I would say $f\mathcal{R}g$ iff $\langle f-g|f-g\rangle=0$, but I don't know if that defines an equivalence relation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathcal{B} = \{1, x, x^2,\dots, x^k,\dots\}$ is a set of linearly independent elements of $\mathcal{L}^2([a,b])$, but it is neither a vector space basis of $\mathcal{L}^2([a,b])$ nor an orthonormal basis (= onb) of the Hilbert space $\mathcal{L}^2([a,b])$. However, the Gram-Schmidt procedure allows to transform $\mathcal{B}$ into a set of polynomials $\mathcal{P} =  \{p_n(x) \mid n = 0, 1, 2, \dots \}$ which forms an onb of $\mathcal{L}^2([a,b])$.

$\mathbb{C}[x]$ is the polynomial ring over $\mathbb{C}$ in one variable $x$. This is a purely algebraic construct characterized by a certain universal property. See for example http://math.mit.edu/~mckernan/Teaching/12-13/Spring/18.703/l_21.pdf. The monomials $x^n$, $n = 0,1,2, ...$, form a (countable) basis of $\mathbb{C}[x]$. Hence $\mathbb{C}[x]$ is vector space of countably  infinite dimension.

Clearly $\mathbb{C}[x]$ can be regarded as a subspace $C^{\omega}([a,b])$. In fact, each $p(x) \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ can be identified with the polynomial function $t \mapsto p(t), t \in [a,b]$.

It is obvious that $\mathbb{C}[x]$ is a proper subset of $C^{\omega}([a,b])$. Even more, $C^{\omega}([a,b])$ is a vector space of uncountable dimension. However, it is impossible to *explicitly* describe an uncountable basis.

Comment: In a Hilbert space $(\mathcal{H},\langle·|·\rangle)$, isn't every orthonormal basis of $(\mathcal{H},\langle·|·\rangle)$ also a vector space basis of $\mathcal{H}$? The first sentence seems to imply that it is possible for a set of vectors to be a onb of a Hilbert space but not a basis of the vector space that Hilbert space is defined on. Thank you very much for your answer, by the way.

Comment: Each onb is a set of linear independent vectors, but in an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space an onb is not a vector space basis. Consider for example $\ell^2$ = space of sequences $(x_n)$ such that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \lvert x_n \rvert^2$ converges. Then the set of all $e^i$, $e^i_n = 1$ for $n=i$, $e^i_n = 0$ else, is an onb of $\ell^2$ (each $(x_n) \in \ell^2$ can be written as a convergent sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x_n e^n$). However, it is not a vector space basis because the $e^i$ only generate the subspace all sequences $(x_n)$ such that $x_n = 0$ for all but finitely many $n$.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthonormal_basis.